# Derivative of Input in nonlinear State Space representation

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, linearization

I am dealing with obtaining an space state representation of a nonlinear differential equation that arises from an inverted pendulum. It includes some terms that reflect the fact pendulum is controlled in a PID similarly fashion.

The original EOM would be like this:

$$ \ddot{\theta}(t)=a_1\sin{\theta(t)} -a_2\theta(t)-a_3\dot{\theta}(t)-a_4\int_0^\tau{\theta(\tau)d\tau} 
+b_1u(t) $$

So if I derive it once to get rid of the integral term, the equation takes the form:

$$ \dddot{\theta}(t)=a_1\cos{\theta(t)}\dot{\theta}(t) -a_2\dot{\theta}(t)-a_3\ddot{\theta}(t)-a_4\theta(t) +b_1\dot{u}(t) $$

And form here I'm kinda stuck and second guessing myself a little bit. If I want to express the equation in state space form, $\vec{x}(t)=\mathbf{f}\{\theta(t),\dot{\theta}(t),\ddot{\theta}(t),u(t)\}$ to then linearize it to obtain the classic form, $\dot{\vec{x}}(t) = A(\sigma)\vec{x}(t) + B(\sigma)\vec{u}(t)$...

Kinda my question would be how to deal with that input derivative.. Could a change of variable be the right thing to do? Like set $v(t)=\dot{u}(t)$ and go from there.. or consider a vector input $\vec{u}(t)=[u(t), \dot{u}(t)]$?

I mean, for instance if I would want to obtain the TF of that system for a particular operation point, I could get back from the change of variable knowing that $V(s)=sU(s)$, but not sure if I would get the same results with the extended input vector.

Comment: I am a bit curious how you got the integral of angle into the equations?

Comment: ohh.. my system of study operates in closed-loop and a way of modeling it was to try to fit a PID-like controller on the equations.. and see if something useful could be extrapolated from it.. the idea came from a research paper.. I want to have it on SS form, since I need to add more inputs (mostly unwanted inputs) to pursue a more general situation.

Comment: @Road_King : If you already have a PID similar controller applied , why is there a control signal $u(t)$ in your equation ?

Comment: @abc1455 u is an input, not the control input.. I didn't follow the usual notation here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

Let $x_1 = \dot{\theta}$, $x_2 = \theta$ and $x_3(t) = x_3(0) + \int_0^t \theta(\tau) d \tau$.

Then we obtain
$\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \sin x_2 - a_2 x_2 - a_3 x_1 - a_4 x_3 +b_1 u \\ x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix} $.

Note however, the behaviour of this system matches the original system **iff** $x_3(0) = 0$. From a transfer function perspective they are of course equivalent.

Comment: That could work I guess... at the end (if $x_3(0)=0$) they have the same tf... but what would happen if $x_3(0)\neq0$

Comment: It depends on what you are modelling. If $x_3(0) = 0$ represents a hard physical constraint then, for example, it makes no sense to model a noise input on the $x_3$ channnel. If the integrator is a hardware device subject to noise then it would make sense.

Comment: The integrator is more like a bias removal term. It's not a physical device. What I am wondering is for any equilibrium point other than zero, would imply an nonzero value on $x_3$ channel..

Comment: I don't know what that means so it is hard to comment. Usually physical dynamics are Newtonian so they are second order. Generally I would separate modelling from other tricks.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, so no worries at all. I agree with the second order nature of physical dynamics, the trick here is that on this paper I'm following, they kinda develop the system as this: inverted pendulum rotating about its pivot point (classical IP) + controller (modeled as a rotational suspension device, this is, a spring and damper but acting on $\theta(t) and \dot{\theta}(t)$). They want to identify  the closed loop transfer function of this system so they need an extra term that removes their bias, so then they add the third integral term based on that parameter.

Comment: So then they have something similar to a PID controller, added to the equation of motion, and when deriving it to get rid of the integral it ends with a third order transfer function. I want to expand that to any operating point of the pendulum, so I can study the model linearized for positions other than the vertical. So I kinda wanted to get the state-space nonlinear form first and then linearize it to have the standard LIT form parametrized for any $\theta_0$ point.

Comment: I would model the PID unit and the pendulum separately then.

Comment: @Road_King : you could have used your original control signal to remove the non-linear term $a_1 sin(\theta)$ to end up with a linear system and used the transfer function directly .

Comment: @abc1455 yeah.. But I'm working on a generalization of that case, on which the controller do not remove completely the nonlinear term (like to study how the system responds to certain levels of that term). And trying to avoid falling into nonlinear control techniques or even time varying on the most sense.

Comment: @Road_King : If you have some doubts about $x_3(0) \neq 0 $ , you have to notice that you are the one who gets to choose what $x_3(0)$ is , since $x_3$ is the integral of the angle it has no real physical meaning in your system .

Comment: @Road_King : The integrator is a part of the controller and not part of the system dynamics , so you can choose what is its initial condition , unlike the angle for example which is a part of the dynamics and you have no control over its initial condition .

Comment: @abc1455 nice insight, thanks so much!

Comment: @Road_King you're welcome